# How to kill a player when they touch a block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a multiplayer parkour map on bedrock edition, and I have it set up where when a player steps on a grass block they die.
But when a player steps on a grass block it just kills anyone who touches it.

First: A repeat command block (set to always active and unconditional)

```
execute @e [type=player] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ grass
```

And then I have a chain command block (set to conditional and always active)

```
kill @e [type=player]
```

And it does work..... *IF* in singleplayer only. (which is not at all what I want)

Thank y'all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this command in a repeating, always active, unconditional command block:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 kill
```

This will execute the command `kill` at all players (`@a ~ ~ ~`) that have a grass block underneath them (`detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0`).